# Wordpress - redirecting to product sub-category on separate page

Tags: wordpress, categories, product

I have a wordpress website and I have shown product categories on my home page using `[product_categories columns="2"]` shortcode. What I want is when somebody clicks on one of the product categories, it takes them to the product sub-category may be on separate page and I want the sub-categories to be shown exactly like the parent-categories shown on my homepage.

I have already created the sub-categories in my wordpress admin panel but unable to show them on separate page when somebody clicks on parent category. How to achieve that result ?

Comment: [product_categories columns="2"] is this shortcode is only showing parent product categories?

Comment: @RajkumarGour yes and when somebody clicks on one the categories, I want to show sub-category just like I have shown on my homepage

Answer (score 1):

you can create a taxonomy-product_cat.php file. and where you can get the current category id and use below function to get its clid category

```
get_term_children( $current_term_id, $taxonomy );
```

after that you can use clild product category ids to display them

you can use below function to get current product category id

```
$queried_object = get_queried_object();
```